# python regular expression matching anything

Tags: python, regex

My regular expression isnt doing anything to my string.

python

```
data = 'random\n<article stuff\n</article>random stuff'
datareg = re.sub(r'.*<article(.*)</article>.*', r'<article\1</article>', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print datareg
```

i get

```
random
<article stuff
</article>random stuff
```

i want

```
<article stuff
</article>
```

Comment: Aw, c'mon: Not [Cthulhu Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) again.

Comment: @pillmuncher: it looks like malformed HTML to me, so I doubt a HTML parser would be able to work with it very easily.

Comment: @Blender: I think youÄre right. But the substitution seems to be no valid XML either. I wonder, what does one need broken XML for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) doesn't actually make your regex multiline in the way you want it to be.

> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

[`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) does:

> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; **without this flag, `'.'` will match anything *except* a newline.**

Change `flags=re.MULTILINE` to `flags=re.DOTALL` and your regex will work.